# Pygame Set Mouse Cursor from Bitmap

Tags: python, pygame, mouse-cursor

I'm making an image editor using pygame and I was wondering if it was possible to change the mouse cursor to something more suitable (for instance a circle or rectangle) for brushes.
Pygame has a really weird way of doing it that I'm not sure would work very well. Is there a way I can write to a bitmap and then use that?

If there is a way to do it with Python generally, that would work too I suppose.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another option is to simply [hide](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_visible) the cursor, [load](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) any arbitrary bitmap that you like and [draw](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.blit) it every frame [where the cursor is](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos).

Answer (score 6):

You can load cursors in PyGame with [pygame.cursors.load_xbm](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html#pygame.cursors.load_xbm) -- that's black and white cursors only, of course, a well-documented limitation of PyGame, per [its docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html) (and I quote):

> Pygame only supports black and white
>   cursors for the system.

For XBM format docs, see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap).  You can prep such files e.g. with the PIL library, per [its docs](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-xbm.htm).

Comment: Is this the only method available? It doesn't seem like it would provide enough user feedback. I could use hover colors but a cursor seems like a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since @SapphireSun asked in a comment about another way, I'd like to present a different answer, and this is drawing the cursor manually.  I guess this is what @Mizipzor suggests in his answer, so maybe this is just an elaboration.

First Hide the mouse-cursor, then every time the screen-frame is updated, "manually" paint the cursor:

```
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)  # hide the cursor

# Image for "manual" cursor
MANUAL_CURSOR = pygame.image.load('finger_cursor_16.png').convert_alpha()

# In main loop ~
    ...

    # paint cursor at mouse the current location
    screen.blit( MANUAL_CURSOR, ( pygame.mouse.get_pos() ) )
```

This method allows the PyGame program to have any sort of bitmap for the cursor.  There may be some trickiness around getting the "click" hot-spot in the right location, but this could be achieved by setting a transparent cursor, with the hot-spot at the position to match the custom bitmap.  See the [manual](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_cursor) for details.

```
# transparent 8x8 cursor with the hot-spot at (4,4)
pygame.mouse.set_cursor((8,8),(4,4),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

I am not sure how I feel about multi-coloured cursors, but at least it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

you could also just simply load a image to replace of draw something instead of it.
For an example:

```
cursor = pygame.image.load('CURSOR IMAGE FILE HERE')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)  # hide the cursor

#write this in the loop
coord = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
screen.blit(cursor, coord)
```

If you just want to replace it with a shape you could just do this:

```
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)  # hide the cursor
coord = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
pygame.draw.(shape here)(screen, (color), (coord, width, height))
```

Hope this helped!